# Appcelerator studio won't start (no loading screen)

Tags: appcelerator

I'm trying to run appcelerator studio in my Desktop.
AMD Athlon II x4 640 3.00 GHz
Ram 4gb
64bit win 8.1
120Gb SSD Samsung 840 EVO

so, in my laptop i7 8gb ram etc.. run smoothly.
When I'm trying to start the studio doesn't respond, not even in task manager.
I'm using CLI and work fine..
I can't find any log file. Which appc studio keep in workspace which one I have no create yet because I can't open the studio.
I run the command appc platform to start the studio from the CMD but nothing happens and this message appears:

`{"success":false,"description":"platform command usage: appcelerator platform <api> <method/arguments>"}`

I uninstalled AVAST and check first the blocked programs, but nothing..

I disabled Windows firewall too.

Reinstalled the studio many times using different versions of node. But nothing.
And of course I tried to come in contact with the appc team but I can't....

I'm thinking about 4Gb ram limitation; if that blocks the program from starting.

I also try to open the program logged in and logout from CLI.

Any idea? any one with the same problem?
I am not stuck in loading screen the studio try to verify my account and communicate with server.
Studio just won't start at all.
I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: In general, questions about software used by programmers are on-topic here, but this sounds like more of an issue with your computer or license. Are you sure that you're connected to the Internet and that you have properly entered your licensing information? What happened when you contacted the vendor? They couldn't help you?

Comment: Yes, yes.. all my account informations are correct.. i try to contact appc teamn but the platform dosnt work ... and when  i oress ask question in their cummunity throw me here..
i know maybe is my machine's problem. but in case is a general problem i post it here

Answer (score 0):

sorry for your issue.

First - I am assuming your running Windows (Linux is no longer supported)

The CLI command your using `appc platform` does not launch studio. That is used for accessing platform APIs and thus requires you to provide an API to use.

To launch studio from the CMD line on Windows you would need to `cd` into your Appcelerator Studio directory and run the associated program. When installing studio, we do put an icon on the desktop, which is by far the easiest way to start it up.

Your right about your RAM limitation. While you'll find that studio does "run" it will be extremely slow, especially once you start using the Android / Windows emulators etc. Windows takes up 1-2GB of Ram on its own, leaving very little for any development tools.

Our recommended configuration for Windows machines is:
* Windows 8.1 or higher
* 16GB of RAM

I would also think about a faster proc as well.

We are in the process of updating our [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Prerequisites) on the pre-reqs' as its a bit misleading. While we say 4GB of RAM is suitable, what we are talking about is 4GB of 'free memory' on top of everything else you have running, not 4GB of total system memory.

Comment: i used cmd too to open the studio from instalation folder in roaming but nothing.
i din know that about platform thanks for information.
So my ram limitation didnt block the program to start. just slow the development ok its clear.
i tried everything. turn on in safe mode. disable unistall antivirus. windows firewall, and try to add an exception too. The studio wont open..
Is there any way to get a log file?

Comment: yes you should be able to search the Roaming directory for *.log file, if you can post it here.

Comment: this popup when i reinstal lthe appcelerator studio that means i already have the npm installed? im confused.. i wonder if i have to delete everything content related with appcelerator. to make complete unistall.. any setting.
[link](http://postimg.org/image/500rtc5px/)

installation path: C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Appcelerator Studio
There is not log file